# How to Catch Database Commumication failure using Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

How do Catch Database Commumication failure using Hibernate?, At the time of running application if the connection of DB is there then I got entitymanager else i didnt get entitymanager from spring containar.
How to get the connection is open or closed

Answer (score 0):

What JPA provider are you using?

If you are using EclipseLink, with its connection pooling, it should auto detect a dead connection after a failure and retry the execution of the query on a new connection.

Otherwise, depending on what DataSource or connection pool you are using you can enable connection testing to ensure the connection is valid before use (this does add overhead though).

You could also catch the JPA exception and retry your JPA transaction.

Comment: I am using Hibernate JPA provider. How can i catch JPA exception? and how i enable connection testing for checking connection is valid?

Answer (score 0):

In general you should get Session object using say `org.hibernate.SessionFactory` object and method `getCurrentSession()` or `openSession()`. Once you have Session object which is actually instance of `org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl` you can get Connection object  using `connection()` method.

Example:

```
((SessionImpl)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).connection().isClosed();
```

You can use [c3p0 connection pool](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/)  which has option to check connection before to use it.

Comment: I didnt get session after failure of the DB connection so how could i catch exception

Comment: So first of all ensure that your connections are pooled and tested. If you get connection failure while starting or commiting transaction you will get org.hibernate.TransactionException.